# Is there any way to find a word from a csv file with only the first few letters?

Tags: python, csv, telegram-bot

I'm a beginner at programming. I created an English-Malayalam dictionary bot for telegram in python. It is working fine. But I'm thinking about an upgrade. The database is a CSV file (tab separated). The bot searches for the input word and replies with the results (Malayalam definitions) to the user.
[check screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSai3.png)

It searches for the entire word. But I want the bot to give me the results with only two or three letters as input. For example, when I type "ent", I want the results of all words starting with "ent". [Screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qxtk.png)

My current code is below. (searching section)

```
import csv

def malayalamDict(word):
    mDict = []
    mDef = []
    eWrd = []
    with open("data/olam-enml.csv", "r") as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        for i in r:
            if word in i[0]:
                mDict.append(i[0].split('\t'))
        for j in range(0, len(mDict)):
            mDef.append(str(mDict[j][-1]))
        for k in range(0, len(mDict)):
            eWrd.append(str(mDict[k][1]))
    return mDef, eWrd
```

My CSV file example:

```
id english_word part_of_speech definition
14007   Entity  n   സത്ത
14008   Entity  n   അസ്‌തിത്വം
14009   Entity  n   വസ്‌തു
138185  Entity  n   നിലനില്‌പ്‌
138186  Entity  n   ഉണ്മ
207395  Entity  n   നിലനില്പ്
```

Please somebody help me here.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `if i[0].startswith(word):`

Comment: Yes, I think it is. I'll try this. Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar: Please post this as an answer, so the OP can accept it (if it works), and so that other users can upvote it and give you reputation! ;-).

Comment: If `word` is the first few letters, `word in i[0]:` will also be true. I'm not sure why you need this more specific test.

Comment: @Barmar It didn't work. if i[0].startswith(word):  is not True. ///If word is the first few letters, word in i[0]: will also be true. I'm not sure why you need this more specific test./// - I'm trying to add the word suggestion feature to the bot.

Comment: `word` is `"ent"` and it doesn't find words that begin with `ent`?

Comment: @Barmar Now, it is not giving results for both "ent" and "entity".

Comment: instead of creating separated list you should keep all in one lista with nested lists or dictionares (one row == one dictionary). Or you should use `pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: You should run all in one `for i in r:`

Comment: Can you show a sample of the CSV?

Comment: You have `Entity` so `ent` may not find it - you would have to compare `lower()` or `upper()` chars.

Comment: @Barmar You can download the CSV file from [here](https://olam.in/open/enml/olam-enml.csv.zip)

Comment: maybe first you should use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"`. In example CSV it uses spaces not `tab` so it doesn't find any elements because it doesn't split row in cells.

Comment: I see other problem - you get `i[0]` before split so you check `word` with `14007   Entity  n   സത്ത`, not with `Entity`

Comment: @furas I'm using this 'word = wrd.capitalize()' before this section. Let me try 'pandas.DataFrame'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check first letters you can use `text.startswith(word)` but you have few other problems which makes that it may not work.

You compare `ent` with `Entity` and you should use `lower()` (or `upper()`) to compare it with `entity`.

You check `word` with `i[0]` before `split()` so you compare it with `14007   Entity  n   സത്ത`. You should simply use `csv_reader(..., delimiter='\t')` to split it automatically - and then you can compare with second column `row[1]`

This code works with your file `csv` which you added in your comment [here](https://olam.in/open/enml/olam-enml.csv.zip) - it gives 307 results for `ent`

```py
import csv

def malayalam_dict(word):
    malayalam_definition = []
    english_word = []
    
    word = word.lower()

    with open("olam-enml.csv", "r") as f:
        cvs_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')

        #for (id_, english, part_of_speech, definition) in cvs_reader:
        for row in cvs_reader:
            #(id_, english, part_of_speech, definition) = row
            if row[1].lower().startswith(word):
                malayalam_definition.append(row[-1])
                english_word.append(row[1])
                
    return malayalam_definition, english_word

definitions, words = malayalam_dict('ent')

print(len(definitions))
```

To make code more readable I uses full names for variables.

See more: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for PythonCde](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-008/)

---

**EDIT:**

I would keep results as pairs `(definition, english)` instead of separated lists.

I would also use regex to use more complex searching

```
import csv
import re

def malayalam_dict(word, regex=False):
    results = []
    
    word = word.lower()
    
    with open("olam-enml.csv", "r") as f:
        cvs_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
        #for (id_, english, part_of_speech, definition) in cvs_reader:
        for row in cvs_reader:
            #(id_, english, part_of_speech, definition) = row
            if regex:
                if re.findall(word, row[1].lower()):
                    results.append( (row[-1], row[1]) )
            else:
                if row[1].lower().startswith(word):
                    results.append( (row[-1], row[1]) )
                
    return results

results = malayalam_dict('ent')               # normal `startswith()`
results = malayalam_dict('^ent', regex=True)  # regex

print(len(results))

for number, (definition, english) in enumerate(results, 1):
    print(f'{number:4} | {english:20}: {definition}')
```

Result:

```
307
   1 | Entail              : പ്രത്യേകപിന്‍തുടര്‍ച്ചക്രമം
   2 | Entail              : ദാനവിക്രയാദി അധികാരങ്ങളില്ലാതെ തലമുറയായി അനുഭവിക്കുന്നതിനു നല്‍കിയ സ്വത്ത്‌
   3 | Entail              : അന്യാധീനപ്പെടുത്താന്‍ പാടില്ലാത്ത വിധം നല്‍കുക
   4 | Entail              : ചുമത്തുക
   5 | Entail              : അനിവാര്യമാക്കിത്തീര്‍ക്കുക
   6 | Entail              : കൈമാറ്റം ചെയ്യാന്‍ അധികാരമില്ലാത്ത വസ്‌തുവകകളുടെ പിന്‍തുടര്‍ച്ചാവകാശം
   7 | Entail              : ആവശ്യമായി വരുക
   8 | Entail              : അന്യാധീനപ്പെടുത്താന്‍ പാടില്ലാത്ത വിധം അവകാശം കൊടുക്കുക
   9 | Entail              : കൈമാറ്റം ചെയ്യാന്‍ അധികാരമില്ലാത്ത വസ്തുവകകളുടെ പിന്‍തുടര്‍ച്ചാവകാശം
  10 | Entailer            : അവകാശമായി വിട്ടുകൊടുക്കുന്നവന്‍
  11 | Entangle            : കുടുക്കുക
  12 | Entangle            : അകപ്പെടുത്തുക
  13 | Entangle            : സങ്കീര്‍ണ്ണീകരിക്കുക
  14 | Entangle            : കെട്ടുപിണയുക
  15 | Entangle            : വിഷമിക്കുക
  16 | Entangle oneself with: മറ്റുള്ളവരുമായി വഴക്കടിച്ച്‌ പ്രശ്‌നമുണ്ടാക്കുക

  ...
```

Comment: This is my result [link](https://imgur.com/a/5F9R7Sh)